# Is it necessary to rewrite C# classes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have a project that contains the logic for my application.

I've exposed a rest service that takes JSON input, which is passed to the back-end and worked with.

I'm now creating a web UI that allows users to create the necessary JSON.

I have C# classes such as

```
public class Template 
{
    public string TemplateName {get; set;}
    public List<Column> Columns {get; set;}
}

public class Column
{
    public string ColumnName {get; set;}
}
```

So I've been re-creating these classes in JavaScript.

```
function Template(templateName, columns) {
    this.TemplateName = name;
    this.Columns = columns;
}


function Column(columnName) {
    this.ColumnName = columnName;}
```

And my web page has some text fields that I input information, and from that information I'm creating the objects, and then I convert them to JSON.

```
    $scope.buttonClick = function () {

        var column = new Column('cName',$scope.selectedDataType,
            $scope.selectedDataType,
            $scope.selectedGenerator,
            'TEST');

        var columns = [];
        columns.push(column);

        var template = new Template($scope.TemplateName, $scope.RowCount, columns);

        var jsonbody = JSON.stringify(template);

        console.log(jsonbody);
    }
```

I'm obviously repeating work here, rewriting all the classes in JS and that FEELS wrong. Is there a better way? Should I be doing something different?

Comment: It's not JS, but Typewriter is a VS extension that generates TypeScript from C# files.  Similar extensions likely exist for JS.

Comment: I am going to second Typescript. It is a superset of javascript and allows for type safety. If you go that route the preferred method would be to create a TypeScript interface for each c# Type that your script code has to work with. Using a tool or vs extension it is straight forward to generate the typescript interfaces from c# code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that it depends. If you have a small application with only a few classes, you may decide that the overhead is relatively low, and there is no benefit to doing anything else. However, you are right to say that it *feels* wrong. Doing everything by hand opens you up to all kinds of potential bugs.

As Amy mentioned, there are low impact tools such as Typewriter that allow you to generate equivalent Typescript.

If your app is larger, you might find it useful to start using something like [NSwag](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag), which extends [Swagger](https://swagger.io/), and allows you to have more of an end-to-end solution for linking your client application to your APIs.

There are lots of variations and points between.